# Maven Compilation error: cannot find symbol with local dependecies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

When I run "mvn compile" on my Maven project, I get error messages like the following:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/rommelrico/Documents/GitHub/github.sandiego.edu/SeniorSurvey/src/main/java/edu/sandiego/custom/SeniorSurveyPortlet.java:[4,37] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Person
location: package com.sghe.luminis.person.entity
```

I have a set of closed-source files that I installed as follows:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=aspectjrt.jar -DgroupId=some.group -DartifactId=aspectjrt -Dversion=1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And when I list the Maven dependencies, they appear to be fine (no errors):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SeniorSurvey Portlet 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ SeniorSurveyPortlet ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    some.group:util-taglib:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:sqljdbc4:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:util-java:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:luminis-security-base:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:luminis-security-policy:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO]    javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO]    some.group:util-bridges:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:aspectjrt:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:luminis-session:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO]    some.group:luminis-dal:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    taglibs:standard:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO]    some.group:spring-2.5.5:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    some.group:jasig-cas-client-core-3.1.3:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:spring-security-cas-client-2.0.5.RELEASE:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:spring-security-core-2.0.5.RELEASE-mod:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO]    some.group:luminis-person:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    some.group:luminis-util:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    some.group:luminis-security-springweb:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-taglib:jar:2.0.0:provided
[INFO]    javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    javax.portlet:portlet-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.177 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-24T12:02:59-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My POM dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.portals.pluto</groupId>
        <artifactId>pluto-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasig-cas-client-core-3.1.3</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>luminis-dal</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>luminis-person</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>luminis-security-base</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>luminis-security-policy</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>luminis-security-springweb</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>luminis-session</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>luminis-util</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-2.5.5</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client-2.0.5.RELEASE</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core-2.0.5.RELEASE-mod</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And my IntelliJ settings: 
[image]

In IntelliJ, my imports and code is not "red" meaning it can resolve it to the jar files. But when I run mvn compile it says "cannot find symbol". What's more frustrating is that if I do the same thing in Eclipse, it works fine, but in IntelliJ it doesn't. What is the problem? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: If **mvn install** does not work from command line, then your project is simply broken.

Comment: @Meo If I remove all the local dependencies, the project works just fine. It errors out only when I add the local libraries. And like I say, this works fine in Eclipse, so I don't think the project is "simply broken"... But in any case, how do I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Clearly, if it does not work in pure Maven, and works in Eclipse, then Eclipse is doing something wrong. You should define all dependencies in your pom and not hack it in IDE.

Comment: "If I remove all the local dependencies, the project works just fine. It errors out only when I add the local libraries." What does that mean? Don't add them then.

Comment: @Meo Thanks. I got it working. As it turns out, I added the dependencies correctly but the jar files did not contain the classes that I thought they did. I am dumb.

For the sake of anyone reading this from the future, I was trying to add security libraries that deal with authentication/authorization. In Eclipse, I can "hack" it by manually creating a lib folder and dropping all the JARs in that folder and not including them as dependencies in the POM but Eclipse and pure Maven don't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold CTRL and click on the person class on line 4 of SeniorSurveyPortlet.

You should see the file location in the IntelliJ window title.

The location should be an artifact in your local maven repo (i.e a directory named .m2).

The path contains the groupId, artifactId and version.

Ensure that the dependency is listed correctly in the pom.

Comment: Not quite the answer, but I'm marking it as such because your reply was helpful in finding my answer. As it turns out, I was doing everything right but the JAR did not have the classes I thought they did. Once I included the correct dependencies, the project compiled just fine.