# maven site throws cannot find symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho, maven-site-plugin

I've an E4 project that build (mvn install) and launches fine inside eclipse and as a stand alone product. When I run a `mvn site` I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site (default-site) on project roadrunner.rcp.parent: Error generating mav                                                            en-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:aggregate:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - C:\GIT\roadrunner-rcp\plugins\roadrunner.ui.ctg\src\com\acme\wh\ui\ctg\chart\Graph.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] import javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] symbol:   class FXCanvas
[ERROR] location: package javafx.embed.swt
[ERROR] C:\GIT\roadrunner-rcp\plugins\roadrunner.ui.btg\src\com\acme\wh\ui\game\Container.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] import javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] symbol:   class FXCanvas
[ERROR] location: package javafx.embed.swt
[ERROR] C:\GIT\roadrunner-rcp\plugins\roadrunner.rcp.layout.board\src\com\acme\wh\rcp\layout\board\toolcontrols\Toolbar.java:4: error                                                            : cannot find symbol
[ERROR] import javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas;
```

Here the the maven version

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T06:57:37-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

I'm not sure why site fails with the error.
Here is the pom file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- The Basics -->
    <groupId>com.acme.lj.pom</groupId>
    <artifactId>roadrunner-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <!-- Description -->
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>The parent pom that manages high level configurations all roadrunner projects should inherit.</description>

    <properties>
        <!-- TODO: UPDATE THIS WITH EVERY RELEASE -->
        <version.development.startdate>2014-08-07 00:00:00</version.development.startdate>

        <!-- General Properties -->
        <!-- Workaround for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRESOURCES-99 -->
        <buildTimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildTimestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <project.java.version>1.8</project.java.version>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- P2 Configuration -->
        <roadrunner.p2m2.repository.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</roadrunner.p2m2.repository.version>

        <!-- Dependency Properties -->
        <powermock.version>1.5.6</powermock.version>
        <roadrunner-common>1.0-SNAPSHOT</roadrunner-common>
        <roadrunner-channel>6.0-SNAPSHOT</roadrunner-channel>
        <!-- TODO: KEEP UPDATED TO THE VERSION BEING DEVELOPED AGAINST -->
        <board-svcs-channel-env>5.3-SNAPSHOT</board-svcs-channel-env>

        <!-- Plug-in Properties -->
        <clirr-maven-plugin>2.6.1</clirr-maven-plugin>
        <findbugs-maven-plugin.excludeFilterFile>src/etc/findbugs-exclude.xml</findbugs-maven-plugin.excludeFilterFile>
        <findbugs-maven-plugin>3.0.1</findbugs-maven-plugin>
        <maven-assembly-plugin>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin>
        <maven-bundle-plugin>2.5.4</maven-bundle-plugin>
        <maven-changelog-plugin>2.3</maven-changelog-plugin>
        <maven-changes-plugin.module.xmlPath>/src/changes/changes.xml</maven-changes-plugin.module.xmlPath>
        <maven-changes-plugin.module.xmlPath>src/changes/changes.xml</maven-changes-plugin.module.xmlPath>
        <maven-changes-plugin>2.11</maven-changes-plugin>
        <maven-clean-plugin>2.6.1</maven-clean-plugin>
        <maven-clover2-plugin.licenseLocation>http://repo.acme.corp/</maven-clover2-plugin.licenseLocation>
        <maven-clover2-plugin>4.0.4</maven-clover2-plugin>
        <maven-compiler-plugin>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin>
        <maven-dependency-plugin>2.10</maven-dependency-plugin>
        <maven-deploy-plugin>2.8.2</maven-deploy-plugin>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.requireJavaVersion>[1.6,1.9)</maven-enforcer-plugin.requireJavaVersion>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.requireMavenVersion>[3.0.3,4.0.0)</maven-enforcer-plugin.requireMavenVersion>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin>1.4</maven-enforcer-plugin>
        <maven-install-plugin>2.5.2</maven-install-plugin>
        <maven-invoker-plugin>2.0.0</maven-invoker-plugin>
        <maven-jar-plugin>2.6</maven-jar-plugin>
        <maven-javadoc-plugin>2.10.3</maven-javadoc-plugin>
        <maven-jxr-plugin>2.5</maven-jxr-plugin>
        <maven-pmd-plugin>3.5</maven-pmd-plugin>
        <maven-project-info-reports-plugin>2.8</maven-project-info-reports-plugin>
        <maven-release-plugin>2.5.2</maven-release-plugin>
        <maven-resources-plugin>2.7</maven-resources-plugin>
        <maven-site-plugin.doxia-module-markdown>1.6</maven-site-plugin.doxia-module-markdown>
        <maven-site-plugin.moduleparent.siteDirectory>src/site/module-parent/</maven-site-plugin.moduleparent.siteDirectory>
        <maven-site-plugin.noncode.siteDirectory>src/site/module-non-code/</maven-site-plugin.noncode.siteDirectory>
        <maven-site-plugin.parent.siteDirectory>src/site/parent/</maven-site-plugin.parent.siteDirectory>
        <maven-site-plugin.sourcecode.siteDirectory>src/site/module-source-code/</maven-site-plugin.sourcecode.siteDirectory>
        <maven-site-plugin.wagon-ssh>2.9</maven-site-plugin.wagon-ssh>
        <maven-site-plugin>3.4</maven-site-plugin>
        <maven-source-plugin>2.4</maven-source-plugin>
        <maven-surefire-plugin>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin>
        <maven-surefire-report-plugin>2.18.1</maven-surefire-report-plugin>
        <sortpom-maven-plugin>2.4.0</sortpom-maven-plugin>
        <taglist-maven-plugin>2.4</taglist-maven-plugin>
        <tycho-p2-director-plugin.product.id>${project.artifactId}</tycho-p2-director-plugin.product.id>
        <tycho-p2-director-plugin.product.impl.ext />
        <tycho-p2-director-plugin.product.project>${project.artifactId}</tycho-p2-director-plugin.product.project>
        <tycho-version>0.23.1</tycho-version>
        <versions-maven-plugin>2.2</versions-maven-plugin>

        <!-- Build Properties -->
        <wagon-webdav-jackrabbit>2.0</wagon-webdav-jackrabbit>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- I've stripped all the dependencies -->

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- Build Settings -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.ekryd.sortpom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sortpom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${sortpom-maven-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <predefinedSortOrder>custom_1</predefinedSortOrder>
                        <sortDependencies>groupId,artifactId</sortDependencies>
                        <sortPlugins>groupId,artifactId</sortPlugins>
                        <sortProperties>false</sortProperties>
                        <createBackupFile>false</createBackupFile>
                        <lineSeparator>\r\n</lineSeparator>
                        <expandEmptyElements>false</expandEmptyElements>
                        <keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>
                        <nrOfIndentSpace>-1</nrOfIndentSpace>
                        <verifyFail>Warn</verifyFail>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sort</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <instructions>
                            <_nodefaultversion>true</_nodefaultversion>
                            <_nouses>true</_nouses>
                            <_removeheaders>Bnd-LastModified,Build-Jdk,Built-By,Created-By,Tool</_removeheaders>
                            <_snapshot>$(tstamp)</_snapshot>
                            <Bundle-Description>${project.description}</Bundle-Description>
                            <Bundle-DocURL>${project.url}</Bundle-DocURL>
                            <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                            <Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>JavaSE-${project.java.version}</Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            <Bundle-Vendor>${project.organization.name}</Bundle-Vendor>
                            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                            <Import-Package>!com_atlassian_clover,
                                *</Import-Package>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <!-- This execution is needed to create the Manifest for m2e/eclipse -->
                            <id>eclipse-manifest</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>manifest</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-changelog-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-changes-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <xmlPath>${maven-changes-plugin.module.xmlPath}</xmlPath>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>check-changes</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>changes-check</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>validate-changes</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>changes-validate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>pre-site</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-clean-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>${project.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <source>${project.java.version}</source>
                        <target>${project.java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-deploy-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.requireMavenVersion}</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.requireJavaVersion}</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <bannedDependencies>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <!-- Using guava -->
                                            <exclude>com.google.collections:google-collections</exclude>
                                            <!-- Ban all versions of junit less than 4.11.0 due to hamcrest issue -->
                                            <!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#New_Configuration_Maven_3_only_no_reports_configuration_inheritance -->
                                            <exclude>junit:junit:(,4.11.0)</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                        <message>A banned dependency was found! Run 'mvn
                                            enforcer:display-info' to list banned dependencies.</message>
                                    </bannedDependencies>
                                </rules>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-install-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-invoker-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
                        <noLog>true</noLog>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-jar-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <tags>
                            <tag>
                                <!-- Tells maven to ignore this tag
                                    This tag is used in VitalSignContainer -->
                                <name>wbp.parser.entryPoint</name>
                                <placement>X</placement>
                            </tag>
                        </tags>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>package-javadoc</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-jxr-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-pmd-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-project-info-reports-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-release-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <pushChanges>true</pushChanges>
                        <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-resources-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-site-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <locales>en_US</locales>
                        <siteDirectory>${maven-site-plugin.parent.siteDirectory}</siteDirectory>
                        <!-- Do not use the reportPlugins section until http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSITE-484 is fixed. -->
                        <!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#New_Configuration_Maven_3_only_no_reports_configuration_inheritance -->
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                            <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
                            <version>${maven-site-plugin.doxia-module-markdown}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                            <version>${maven-site-plugin.wagon-ssh}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-source-plugin}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>package-source</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <junitArtifactName>junit:junit-dep</junitArtifactName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-report-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>clirr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${clirr-maven-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${findbugs-maven-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${taglist-maven-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${versions-maven-plugin}</version>
                </plugin>

                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.github.ekryd.sortpom</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>sortpom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.2.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>sort</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.4.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <ignoreTychoRepositories>true</ignoreTychoRepositories>
                        <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                        <allowConflictingDependencies>true</allowConflictingDependencies>
                        <environments>
                            <environment>
                                <os>win32</os>
                                <ws>win32</ws>
                                <arch>x86_64</arch>
                            </environment>
                        </environments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <extraClasspathElements>
                            <extraClasspathElement>
                                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                                <scope>system</scope>
                                <!-- Assumes JAVA_HOME is set and points to jre -->
                                <systemPath>${java.home}\lib\jfxswt.jar</systemPath>
                            </extraClasspathElement>
                        </extraClasspathElements>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <products>
                            <product>
                                <id>${tycho-p2-director-plugin.product.id}</id>
                                <rootFolder>${tycho-p2-director-plugin.product.project} - ${project.version}${tycho-p2-director-plugin.product.impl.ext}</rootFolder>
                            </product>
                        </products>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-distributions</id>
                            <goals>
                                <!-- install the product using the p2 director -->
                                <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                                <!-- create zip file with the installed product -->
                                <goal>archive-products</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <deployableFeature>true</deployableFeature>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>

        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.ekryd.sortpom</groupId>
                <artifactId>sortpom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <!-- Maven 3 does not support our dav: snapshot repo out of the box -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
                <version>${wagon-webdav-jackrabbit}</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-changelog-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <type>date</type>
                    <dates>
                        <date implementation="java.lang.String">${version.development.startdate}</date>
                    </dates>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-changes-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filter>component=${jira.component}</filter>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>changes-report</report>
                            <report>jira-report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
                    <detectLinks>true</detectLinks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jxr-plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-pmd-plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-project-info-reports-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Unable to resolve dependency locations due to the following issue: -->
                    <!-- http://devopsnet.com/2010/12/22/dependency-report-causing-maven-builds-to-run-slowly/ -->
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-report-plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>clirr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${clirr-maven-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <minSeverity>info</minSeverity>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${findbugs-maven-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                    <excludeFilterFile>${findbugs-maven-plugin.excludeFilterFile}</excludeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${taglist-maven-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showEmptyDetails>true</showEmptyDetails>
                    <tagListOptions>
                        <tagClasses>
                            <tagClass>
                                <displayName>1. Incomplete Work (TODO, FIXME)</displayName>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>
                                        <matchString>.?[Ff][Ii][Xx][Mm][Ee].?</matchString>
                                        <matchType>regEx</matchType>
                                    </tag>
                                    <tag>
                                        <matchString>.?[Tt][Oo][Dd][Oo].?</matchString>
                                        <matchType>regEx</matchType>
                                    </tag>
                                </tags>
                            </tagClass>
                            <tagClass>
                                <displayName>2. Needing Enhancement (OPTIMIZE, HACK)</displayName>
                                <tag>
                                    <matchString>.?[Oo][Pp][Tt][Ii][Mm][Ii][Zz][Ee].?</matchString>
                                    <matchType>regEx</matchType>
                                </tag>
                                <tag>
                                    <matchString>.?[Hh][Aa][Cc][Kk].?</matchString>
                                    <matchType>regEx</matchType>
                                </tag>
                            </tagClass>
                            <tagClass>
                                <displayName>3. Comments (REVIEW, NOTE, WARNING)</displayName>
                                <tag>
                                    <matchString>.?[Rr][Ee][Vv][Ii][Ee][Ww].?</matchString>
                                    <matchType>regEx</matchType>
                                </tag>
                                <tag>
                                    <matchString>.?[Nn][Oo][Tt][Ee].?</matchString>
                                    <matchType>regEx</matchType>
                                </tag>
                                <tag>
                                    <matchString>.?[Ww][Aa][Rr][Nn][Ii][Nn][Gg].?</matchString>
                                    <matchType>regEx</matchType>
                                </tag>
                            </tagClass>
                            <tagClass>
                                <displayName>4. Deprecations (@deprecated)</displayName>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>
                                        <matchString>@deprecated</matchString>
                                        <matchType>exact</matchType>
                                    </tag>
                                </tags>
                            </tagClass>
                        </tagClasses>
                    </tagListOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${versions-maven-plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <!-- More Project Information -->
    <url>${project.url}</url>
    <inceptionYear>2022</inceptionYear>
    <organization>
        <name>acme Corporation</name>
        <url>http://acme.com/</url>
    </organization>

    <repositories>

        <!-- Stripping all the repos -->

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>

        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>acme-release-internal</id>
            <name>acme Release Internal Artifact Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.acme.corp/internal/repo/</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>atlassian-m2-repository</id>
            <name>Atlassian Maven 2.x Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.atlassian.com/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>acme-release-main</id>
            <name>acme Release Main Artifact Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.acme.corp/main/repo/</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>acme-release-main</id>
            <name>acme Release Main Artifact Repository</name>
            <url>dav:${distribution.repo}/</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>board-repo</id>
            <name>board Snapshot Artifact Repository</name>
            <url>dav:${distribution.snapshot.repo}/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>

        <site>
            <id>acme-main-site</id>
            <name>acme Release Main Artifact Repository</name>
            <url>dav:${distribution.site.url}</url>
        </site>

        <downloadUrl>${distribution.repo}/</downloadUrl>

    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Set this as an activate profile in your Jenkin's Slave's setting.xml to deploy snapshot sites -->
        <profile>
            <id>site-snapshot-distribution</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <distribution.site>http://repo.board.acme.corp/snapshot-site</distribution.site>
            </properties>
            <distributionManagement>
                <site>
                    <id>board-repo-site</id>
                    <name>board Snapshot Site Repository</name>
                    <url>dav:${distribution.site.url}</url>
                </site>
            </distributionManagement>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: It looks like the configuration of the `maven-javadoc-plugin` is not getting applied in its execution. I'm still unsure why. So I deleted my answer for now. Out of ideas...

Comment: I tried it with different versions of maven (3.1.1, 3.2.5, 3.3.3, 3.3.9) but still the same error

Comment: I think you should try to simplify your POM and cut down the noise. Like making a new very simple project. It would be easier to pin-point the issue.

Comment: My issue was a javadoc which had an html table in it, once I removed the table everything runs smoothly. Not sure why the maven-javadoc-plugin doesn't point to the actual error instead complains about import.

Comment: Really? Well, good to keep in mind that this can cause such problems! Maybe the HTML table was not properly formatted?

Comment: I did check the html table and it was well formatted, though it was not a full html, the parent tag was <table>......</table> I'm not sure if javadoc-plugin needs a <html><body><table>......</html> to see this as a valid javadoc. Interestingly the same javadoc has no issues on mvn install

Comment: I think it does need all those. `<table><thead>...<tbody>...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Compilation error: cannot find symbol with local dependecies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024604/maven-compilation-error-cannot-find-symbol-with-local-dependecies)